# Why is Infopath 2010 form view scrolling above the viewing window?

Tags: 2010, infopath

Using Sharepoint 2010 and InfoPath 2010, we have created a multiple view form. The main view of the form is the basic entry form. We have another view in the aspx file that simulates a dialog box with radio button choices and a third view which appears when the user clicks on a button to delete an item on the main view.

When the user clicks delete and the screen changes to the verification to delete view, the InfoPath web part scrolls above the visible viewing window even though there are not any other objects or web parts on that view of the form.  We have checked to see if perhaps there is a webpart at the bottom that makes it scroll up, but nothing is there. We either need to stop the scrolling or get focus on the top of the "window" so that it stays at the top.

Any ideas?
Thanks!